Is there a way to mimic the Google Cloud App Engine Standard Datastore module_id/version_id when doing requests using the regular Datastore client?
In Python (3.10+), I'm trying to find out what Datastore model is responsible for a high amount of traffic and the regular Datastore metrics don't seem to be able to tell me.
I can see that when using App Engine, the module and version id are added to the requests, but outside of App Engine, Datastore requests have module_id/version_id of unknown/unknown:
current situation
I was wondering if there is any way to highjack these fields and add the Datastore kind and source application (or any metadata really) to these Datastore requests.
So far, I've tried playing around with the user agent in the client info of the Datastore client, but no success so far. I've also tried to look through the App Engine Standard Datastore code, but I'm unable to find what part is responsible for adding the module_id and version_id to the request.
Is there anyone with experience with these things that can help me out? (or tell me that what I'm trying to do can't work).
I'm also open to alternate ideas of how to monitor Datastore traffic. I've tried custom metrics, but they seem to limited. I'm keeping log based metrics as a last resort.
